# Understanding .NET assemblies

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, assemblies

When I build a project in a solution in Visual Studio (it can be C# VB.NET F# or else) I suppose that only one assembly per project is generated right?

So if I have a solution containing project 1 2 3 and 4
When I build one by one each project I get 4 assemblies right?

However, is there the possibility to let the builder/compiler generate only one assembly for the entire solution? Or for two projects compiled together?

I mean something like calling the compiler using the command line and setting a target assembly...

Comment: Why don't make just an unique project then?

Comment: @bAN For example because you use different languages in the different projects. Or you want to separate your layers in a compiler enforced way. Or you have common code between multiple solutions.

Comment: @bAN SOrry for being late... well there are needs, sometimes, where a programmer needs to keep separate projects while compiling into a uniqie assembly...

Comment: Ok, it's just curiosity,tx. I doesn't realize there so many reasons..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default there is a 1 to 1 correspondence between projects and assemblies. But you can use a tool like [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=22914587-b4ad-4eae-87cf-b14ae6a939b0) to create one assembly from several.

Comment: WOW ok... thank you CodeInChaos it was helpful... However is there a way to do this using .net compilers??? for example calling them from command line and specify the target assembly???

Comment: I assume you can put such a call into the post build script. But I haven't done anything like that myself.

Comment: @Andry MSBuild could be the right tool here. See this blog entry: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingLanguagesInASingleAssemblyInVisualStudioSeamlesslyWithILMergeAndMSBuild.aspx